Can an Xserver start faster in qemu non-accelerated mode
I am trying to boot a virtual Linux system under Qemu without hardware acceleration, i.e. in interpreted mode. My end goal is to run a Live Linux as a screensaver in Windows; this is why I am running Linux without acceleration and why I am trying to determine what is happening during that very long boot sequence.
The virtual Linux is a current Debian distribution.
The boot functions OK but performance is poor; I get a black screen for about 7 minutes.
Trying to configure the Intel or AMD virtualization hardware assist and changing the BIOS setting isn't an option for me.
Does anyone know how to profile the XServer start, so I can find what the machine is doing during that 7 minute hiatus in the virtual boot process ? I rather doubt that this enormous amount of processing is really necessary.
The XServer is open source so if I knew what it was doing it would probably be fairly easy to revise the code to short-circuit this process.
Here is a video of the boot https://youtu.be/Q_n39c8pUGw .
Here is my Xorg.0.log http://tjcw.freeshell.org/Xorg.0.log

Asking us to download and unzip a file isn't going to be well received. Upload a video to YouTube or something like that, even unlisted and attach that link if you must, or take accurate timings and capture the logs. What is the host hardware and what resources have you assigned to the VM? What research have you done regarding tracking and diagnosing boot timing issues in Linux? Please share that.

Video moved to YouTube as requested. Host hardware is a HP EliteDesk desktop PC. The VM has 1 GB of RAM and 1 CPU; more CPUs make no difference. The time goes in Xserver startup but I don't know where.

What do you have in your Xorg.0.log?

Xorg.0.log added as requested
